# C++: Variable Size 2D array as an argument to a function

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I need the simplest way to solve this issue: 
when i tried to compile the code below, it says you cant use nR outside the body of the function, passing double pointer in declaration of the function does not work, because it did not allow me to cast, :

```
A(int nT, int nR, int arr[][nR]){
for(int i = 0; i< nT; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j< nR; j++){
        cout<< arr[i][j] << endl;}
    }
}

int main(){
int requests[2][3] = { { 1, 2, 3} , { 4, 32, 6 } };
A(2,3, requests );
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't. Do. That. If you want runtime-sized arrays, use `std::vector`, otherwise `std::array`.

Comment: c++ variable sized arrays are called `std::vector`

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz But please not vector<vector<int>>, but plain vector<int> along with slicing.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it if you make your function a template:

```
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
A(int (&arr)[N][M]){
  for(int i = 0; i< N; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++){
        cout<< arr[i][j] << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

And then in main:

```
int main(){
  int requests[2][3] = { { 1, 2, 3} , { 4, 32, 6 } };
  A(requests);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ (and C) arrays are not resizeable and do not contain size information.

To do this you should use `std::vector`